# Donating to US versus Canadian charities to maximizing tax benefits

Tags: united-states, canada, tax-deduction, charity, tax-credit

I am a US citizen and I have the option to make my charitable donations in either the US or Canada for the next few years.  **How do I maximize my tax benefit for a fixed donation size?**

My understanding: the US offers a tax deduction, reducing taxable income by the amount donated,  and necessitating itemization.  Canada offers a tax credit for a percentage of the donation, and so one may still take the standard deduction.  [This percentage is determined](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/chrts-gvng/dnrs/svngs/clmng1b3-eng.html) by the marginal income tax rate (combined provincial and federal), which tends to be higher in Canada than the US.  Also, except for the first $200 donated, the Canadian federal part of the tax credit assumes you're in the highest income tax bracket.  All of these considerations suggests that a Canadian donation maximizes the benefit.

Any other major considerations I may be missing?

(Minor notes: The money will still go to the same charity, the question is just whether I should donate to the US-registered arm or the Canadian-registered arm.  Because I will be working in both the US and Canada, I can take advantage of tax benefits in either of the countries.  I am in Ontario.)

(Note also that it appears that only [*excess* contributions](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p526/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000229824), over the 50% income maximum, may be carried over.)

Comment: Are you a US citizen? Please add this information by editing your answer, not by replying to this comment.  Also, please read the "carried over" rule for charitable deductions carefully. As I understand it, it is only the _excess donations_ for a year that can be carried over. There are also special rules for donations to Canadian organizations. For a brief summary, see [here](http://www.irs.gov/Charities-&-Non-Profits/Charitable-Organizations/Charitable-Contribution-Deductions).

Comment: Thanks, edited.  I am donating to an international charity that can receive in the US or Canada easily, but your note about deductibility for some Canadian charities could be very useful for other.  I can't find anything 100% definitive, but you appear to be correct about only excess donations being carried over. http://www.irs.gov/publications/p526/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000229824

Comment: Are you living/working in Canada such that you owe canadian taxes as well?

Comment: Skinny: Yes, I will owe significant Canadian taxes.

Comment: Have you considered what the tax treaty has to say about this?

Comment: Apparently, you can use donations to a US charity on your Canadian tax form, but it can only be used to reduce your US income.  This precludes getting a tax break from donating to a US charity during years when you don't have US income.  More here: http://www.icnl.org/research/journal/vol3iss3/ig_2.htm

Comment: Be careful, Canada does not recognize many US charities.